# Portmanteau components to the word Dramedy

Tags: portmanteau-words

Is *dramedy* a combination of *drama* + *comedy*?

Or, is it a combination for *drama* + *tragedy*?

Further research seems to show that it is a combination for *drama* + *comedy*.

***Question***:
In that case, what then would be the portmanteau for *drama* + *tragedy*?

Comment: Technically, it should be neither. It only has the suffix *-edy* just as *comedy* and *tragedy* do, so that neither of them is a part of *dramedy*. However, the one who coined the term could have meant something anywhere in the range of possibilities.

Comment: By the way, why the doubt when the dictionaries and even WP have an entry for the word?

Comment: Kris, my question is "In that case, what then would be the portmanteau for drama + tragedy?"

Comment: My point was that lexically, it cannot be the case, hence 'in that case' does not arise. The suffix *-edy* does **not** stand for 'comedy'. However, natural language has its quirks.

Comment: Whatever happened to "tragi-comedy," as in "The whole sordid affair was one big tragi-comedy of errors." Don

Answer (score 2):

'Dramedy' is rather more than simply 'drama + comedy'. It is a dramatic production in which 'the comic elements derive mainly from character and plot development'. (Oxford Dictionaries).

I am not sure if the same concept could exist with 'tragedy', since it is difficult to see how tragedy could be presented other than in the form of a drama.

Whilst there are such things as 'stand-up comics' it is difficult to envisage a 'stand-up tragic'.

Comment: "Dramatic tragedy," perhaps.

Comment: The question is "In that case, what then would be the portmanteau for drama + tragedy?"

Comment: @BlessedGeek But why would you need such a word? I feel sure, had there been such a general requirement, Shakespeare would have coined one.

Comment: Shakespeare also failed to coin "selfie", "socialnetwork", "condom", "transponder" ....

Comment: @BlessedGeek Perhaps because none of them had been invented in his day. But dramatic tragedy clearly had.

Comment: I've seen a few comedies that were pretty tragic.

Answer (score 0):

I second medica in that a tragedy already is a [drama](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drama) (being a production with a serious tone or subject), and therefore any portmanteau would be redundant.

However, if you want to make a portmanteau just for fun, but which would be understandable to people (in which case it is not "what would be" but "what could be"), I suggest "dragedy" or "trama".

The latter is probably better as it looks and sounds a little like "trauma".